# Microsoft Ads 'AccountPerformanceReportRequest' data contract. The deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this contract

Tags: soap, mule, soapui, bing-api, bing-ads-api

I'm trying to use the Microsoft Bing Ads' [Reporting API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/advertising/reporting-service/reporting-service-reference?view=bingads-13) to gather ad performance data such as clicks, spend, etc. programmatically. Below, I describe the steps taken.

There are two issues -

1 - I have to request for user consent again and again as access token
is short lived and refreshed token also giving unauthenticated token
error.
2 - After following the steps I don't get the expected SOAP
Response. Instead I get below response.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <s:Fault>
            <faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundation/dispatcher">a:DeserializationFailed</faultcode>
            <faultstring>The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter https://bingads.microsoft.com/Reporting/v13:ReportRequest. The InnerException message was 'Error in line 13 position 71. Element 'https://bingads.microsoft.com/Reporting/v13:ReportRequest' contains data of the ':AccountPerformanceReportRequest' data contract. The deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this contract. Add the type corresponding to 'AccountPerformanceReportRequest' to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding it to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.</faultstring>
        </s:Fault>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I'm using Postman to test the service and my end goal is to use http to do the same in Mulesoft later. This is the URL I am using

https://reporting.api.bingads.microsoft.com/Api/Advertiser/Reporting/V13/ReportingService.svc

[Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/advertising/guides/authentication-oauth?view=bingads-13)

I have followed their OAuth 2.0 Authentication Flow in that, I have:

- Registered my Application (using the Developer Account)
- Requested user consent (through the Ad account)
- Generated the Access Token and Refresh Token Every time I hit the API.
- **

> I generate a new Access Token by requesting user consent again and again as refreshing
> token is also not working.

**

[Making the Request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/advertising/reporting-service/reporting-service-operations?view=bingads-13)

The documentation describes a Reporting Service Operation which follows an asynchronous approach. First we need to use SubmitGenerateReport to make a request to the Reporting Service. This returns a ResponseRequestId which we can then use to repeatedly poll the service using PollGenerateReport till we get the requested report in response.

[SubmitGenerateReport](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/advertising/reporting-service/submitgeneratereport?view=bingads-13#request-soap)

SubmitGenerateReport has to be in SOAP XML Format as stated here. Following is the document I generated for my use case looking at the provided example in the documentation. Action I am passing as header attribute - SOAPAction:SubmitGenerateReport

```
<x:Envelope
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
        xmlns:v="https://bingads.microsoft.com/Reporting/v13"
        xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <x:Header>
        <v:AuthenticationToken>****</v:AuthenticationToken>
        <v:CustomerAccountId>****</v:CustomerAccountId>
        <v:CustomerId>****</v:CustomerId>
        <v:DeveloperToken>****</v:DeveloperToken>
    </x:Header>
    <x:Body>
        <v:SubmitGenerateReportRequest>
        <v:ReportRequest i:type="AccountPerformanceReportRequest">
            <v:Format>Csv</v:Format>
            <v:ReportName>AccountPerformanceReportRequest</v:ReportName>
            <v:Aggregation>Summary</v:Aggregation>
        </v:ReportRequest>
    </v:SubmitGenerateReportRequest>
    </x:Body>
</x:Envelope>
```

I even tried passing all the input variables, scope, time etc but getting some error again. I understand error clearly tells me where the error is but the report types I am using are given in Microsoft [documentations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/advertising/guides/report-types?view=bingads-13).

Any help and suggestion would be really helpful.

Comment: what is appropriate prefix in this comment "derived type specified here with the appropriate prefix " ?
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/advertising/reporting-service/submitgeneratereport?view=bingads-13#request-soap

Comment: So you are getting this error when sending the request through postman? or through mule?

Comment: This error is coming while sending request through postman.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> #### 1. I have to request for user consent again and again as access token is short lived and refreshed token also giving unauthenticated token error.

I would like to point you to these tutorial, as reference for my code below.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/advertising/guides/get-started?view=bingads-13
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/advertising/guides/authentication-oauth-quick-start?view=bingads-13

In the first step, you fetch code, for this you need browser verification.

```
$clientId = '...'
Start-Process "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=$clientId&scope=openid%20profile%20https://ads.microsoft.com/msads.manage%20offline_access&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient&state=ClientStateGoesHere&prompt=login"

$code = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient?code=<code>&state=ClientStateGoesHere'
$code = $code -match 'code=(.*)\&'
$code = $Matches[1]
```

Now, using this code, you get accessToken/refreshToken.

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token -ContentType application/x-www-form-urlencoded -Method POST -Body "client_id=$clientId&scope=https://ads.microsoft.com/msads.manage%20offline_access&code=$code&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flogin.microsoftonline.com%2Fcommon%2Foauth2%2Fnativeclient"

$oauthTokens = ($response.Content | ConvertFrom-Json)
```

Since, this access token `$oauthTokens.access_token` will expire after one hour, use the refresh token to get new access and refresh tokens. This process you need to do periodically, say on 1/2 hourly basis.

Process to refresh is the following. This does not require you to login.

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token -ContentType application/x-www-form-urlencoded -Method POST -Body "client_id=$clientId&scope=https://ads.microsoft.com/msads.manage%20offline_access&code=$code&grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=$($oauthTokens.refresh_token)"

$oauthTokens = ($response.Content | ConvertFrom-Json)
```

PS, I'm unclear if we could refresh infinitely or whether it is bound to a day. I verified that an expired accessToken could be renewed via refreshToken via this method after 1.5 hours - no need of generating code again via relogin.

> #### 2. After following the steps I don't get the expected SOAP Response. Instead I get below response

Thank you for providing the detailed soap xmls. I tried the same on my test account and able to repro exact same error message.

Here's the udpated SOAP xml request I used to get it to work.

```xml
<s:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header xmlns="https://bingads.microsoft.com/Reporting/v13">
    <AuthenticationToken i:nil="false">here goes token</AuthenticationToken>
    <CustomerAccountId i:nil="false">176045209</CustomerAccountId>
    <CustomerId i:nil="false">169549046</CustomerId>
    <DeveloperToken i:nil="false">here goes dev Token</DeveloperToken>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <SubmitGenerateReportRequest xmlns="https://bingads.microsoft.com/Reporting/v13">
      <ReportRequest i:nil="false" i:type="AccountPerformanceReportRequest">
        <Format i:nil="false">Csv</Format>
        <ReportName i:nil="false">reportName1</ReportName>
        <!--These fields are applicable if the derived type attribute is set to AccountPerformanceReportRequest-->
        <Aggregation>Summary</Aggregation>
        <Columns i:nil="false">
          <AccountPerformanceReportColumn>Impressions</AccountPerformanceReportColumn>
          <AccountPerformanceReportColumn>Revenue</AccountPerformanceReportColumn>
          <AccountPerformanceReportColumn>AccountName</AccountPerformanceReportColumn>
        </Columns>
        <Scope i:nil="false">
          <AccountIds i:nil="false" xmlns:a1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
            <a1:long>176045209</a1:long>
          </AccountIds>
        </Scope>
        <Time i:nil="false">
          <CustomDateRangeEnd i:nil="false">
            <Day>22</Day>
            <Month>07</Month>
            <Year>2022</Year>
          </CustomDateRangeEnd>
          <CustomDateRangeStart i:nil="false">
            <Day>01</Day>
            <Month>07</Month>
            <Year>2022</Year>
          </CustomDateRangeStart>
        </Time>
      </ReportRequest>
    </SubmitGenerateReportRequest>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Here's the postman result.
[image]

PS, I received error, when some fields were missing. I did not use xml namespaces.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @AAATechGuy , I compared my xml request with your request and found issue in the request. Now it is just working fine. Thanks for your answer.